# Hostname of the current machine in Perl

Tags: windows, linux, perl

How can I get the current machine hostname in Perl? I'm looking for a way that works both in Linux and Windows.

With a websearch I found the module Sys::Hostname, however I can't install it

```
install Sys::Hostname
Going to read '/home/stivlo/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 04 Jun 2011 15:27:16 GMT
Running install for module 'Sys::Hostname'
The most recent version "1.16" of the module "Sys::Hostname"
is part of the perl-5.13.11 distribution. To install that, you need to run
  force install Sys::Hostname   --or--
  install F/FL/FLORA/perl-5.13.11.tar.gz
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 FLORA/perl-5.13.11.tar.gz                    : make NO isa perl
```

My Perl version for this test is 5.10.1 on Linux Ubuntu, and I will use Strawberry Perl on windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's telling you that it's already installed; `Sys::Hostname` has been part of the Perl distribution for years.  You can rely on it being installed unless the machine was last updated somewhere in the early 90s.

Comment: ah funny way to tell me that is already installed! :-) Thank you! I am going to try it then.

Comment: works! thank you again, I'm new to Perl, it's only the second day and I'm reading the "Learning Perl" book... I decided to use Perl for various sys admin stuff, because seems it's still the best tool for this purpose.

Comment: You'll want to look through the standard modules, then; much of what you'l want is already there, especially for basic system administration tasks, and knowing what's there is a prerequisite for effective use of Perl. (Or for that matter Python, Java, or anything else.)

Comment: Is there some rating system in CPAN? My early understanding, that could be wrong, is that there is a lot of good things, but also approximative or broken implementations. What is the approach? Just search and try?

Comment: Pretty much. There have been some attempts at reforming CPAN but none of them caught on; meanwhile most other language module archives have learned from CPAN's mistakes. (The price of being first and therefore having too much of an installed base to be able to update much.)

Comment: Take a look at the website http://perldoc.perl.org. It'll list all the standard modules that come with the last few revisions of Perl. Type `perl -V` and it'll tell you your Perl version, plus where to find all the modules. To see if a module is installed, look at the `perldoc` command. If you can `perldoc` a module, it's installed.

Comment: Another standard module you can look at is the `Config` module. It'll list all sorts of Perl configuration stuff including the OS, Hostname, etc.

Comment: `corelist Sys::Hostname` reports that `Sys::Hostname was first released with perl 5`.  So long as modules have existed, **⸬** has been with us.

Comment: @tchrist: IIRC it predates modules, and existed in a `.pl` form before Perl 5 like `getcwd.pl` and other ancient Perlisms.